# Why is there performance difference between Rust vs C++ in this text / string parsing algorithm?

Tags: c++, performance, rust

I receive very peculiar vehicle data at work in a text file. The file has a large chunk of data as `space` separated values *(42 columns, >1,000,000 rows)*; sometimes having `+/-` signs. I wrote a parser to separate those strings to vector of doubles in Rust and C++. Ran them both in `release (-O3)` mode on Windows 10 and WSL.

Why is Rust implementation 5 times faster than C++? Was something unidiomatic in C++? Below is the bottleneck function:

**Rust implementation:**

```
/// Function separates the string of data into vector of vectors of f64 (double)
/// so that the precision is maintained
fn separate_data_to_vec(str_to_convert: &str) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {
    let reader = BufReader::new(str_to_convert.as_bytes());
    let mut output_vec: Vec<Vec<f64>> = vec![];

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.expect("Coult not read line");
        let mut nums_as_strs: Vec<_> = line.split(" ").collect();
        nums_as_strs.pop();

        let data_nums: Vec<f64> = nums_as_strs
            .iter()
            .map(|v| {
                let v: f64 = v.parse().unwrap_or(0.0);
                v
            })
            .collect();
        output_vec.push(data_nums);
    }

    output_vec
}
```

**C++ Implementation:**

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> separate_data_to_vec(std::string &str_to_convert) {
    std::istringstream reader(str_to_convert);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> output_vec;

    // Tried reserving too but in vain
    // output_vec.reserve(2'000'000);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(reader, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::vector<double> data_nums;
        std::string num_str;

        while (std::getline(ss, num_str, ' ')) {
            if (num_str.empty()) {
                continue;
            }
            // Tried by removing the try catch -- differences stay
            try {
                data_nums.push_back(std::stod(num_str));
            }
            catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
                std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << std::endl;
                data_nums.push_back(0.0);
            }
        }

        output_vec.push_back(data_nums);
    }

    return output_vec;
}
```

Comment: The stream library is unfortunately not all it could be in terms of speed for various reasons. Try breaking up the line in some other way.

Comment: You are doing a lot of extra copies with `output_vec.push_back(data_nums);`.  Try using `output_vec.push_back(std::move(data_nums));` instead and see if there is a difference.

Comment: 1) Your Rust code allocates all space for each inner vector ahead of time, while your C++ vector grows dynamically. 2) Your Rust version only use string slices while your C++ version allocates, although I don't know if that affects much because it reuses the allocations. But your Rust version allocates and grow dynamically for the `Vec<&str>`.

Comment: just a couple random things. `std::stod(num_str)` is notoriously slow which is why `double result; std::from_chars(&num_str.front(), &num_str.back(), result);` was added. Also `output_vec.push_back(data_nums);` should probably be `output_vec.push_back(std::move(data_nums));`

Comment: also using getline to split the string does make an extra copy. So you can `find` to get to the next space and make a string_view with just that part to avoid that copy.

Comment: @PeterT is correct. `std::stod(num_str)` is the 'real' bottleneck. The `output_vec.push_back(std::move(data_nums)` as suggested by @NathanOliver and @PeterT didn't do a lot of difference in the performance. The `from_chars` implementation has some problems on my end.

Comment: @analytical_prat you can use an independent re-implementation like https://github.com/fastfloat/fast_float for example

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica How do you suggest I do that? Can you please provide some ways?

Comment: Peter already mentioned it in his comment. You can simply call `find` to obtain the position of the next space. It's a fairly straight forward loop to write.

Comment: You can likely speed up the Rust function by avoiding the allocation of `nums_as_strs`, iterating over the result of `split(" ")` and popping the last float after parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

After all the comments that were received for the question, I was able to make the following changes:

- Use `fast_float` to convert strings to doubles. There is `std::from_chars` in C++17, however, only with newer compilers (that I didn't have)
- Use `find` rather than streams

The code is faster than the previous; however, still **twice (2 times)** as slow as Rust. The updated C++ code snippet is as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> separate_data_to_vec(std::string &str_to_convert, size_t header_size) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> output_vec;

    size_t start_out;
    size_t end_out = 0;
    while ((start_out = str_to_convert.find_first_not_of('\n', end_out)) != std::string::npos) {
        end_out = str_to_convert.find('\n', start_out);
        std::string line = str_to_convert.substr(start_out, end_out - start_out);

        size_t start_in;
        size_t end_in = 0;
        std::vector<double> data_nums;
        while ((start_in = line.find_first_not_of(' ', end_in)) != std::string::npos) {
            end_in = line.find(' ', start_in);
            std::string num_str = line.substr(start_in, end_in - start_in);
            double result;
            auto answer = fast_float::from_chars(
                num_str.data(), num_str.data() + num_str.size(), result);

            if (answer.ec != std::errc()) {
                data_nums.push_back(0.0);
            } else {
                data_nums.push_back(result);
            }
        }

        output_vec.push_back(std::move(data_nums));
    }

    return output_vec;
}
```

Comment: Too much copying of substrings. Just use ptrs to start and end. `string_view` would be nice but not there pre 17. Make your own equiv.